# jQuery validator calling success if not validated

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am having trouble understanding why validator is showing the success message when fields in my form are blank. I was led to believe that the $.post should not get run until all fields have been validated. Am I missing something simple here. If someone could point out my error I would be grateful. The script I am using is at: http://jqueryvalidation.org/. Thanks

jquery code

```
$(function () {

    $.validator.setDefaults ({

        errorClass: 'form_error',
        errorElement: 'div'
    });

    $("#BA_boxform").validate({
        rules: {
            BA_customer: {
                required: true
            },
            customerdept: {
                required: true
            },
            customeraddress: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_service: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_box: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_destdate: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_authorised: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            BA_customer: {
                required: '<br />* required: You must select a customer'
            },
            customerdept: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a department"
            },
            customeraddress: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a customer address"
            },
            BA_service: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a service level"
            },
            BA_box: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must enter a box number for intake"
            },
            BA_destdate: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must enter a destruction date"
            },
            BA_authorised: {
                required: "<br />* required"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function()   {
                if ($("#BA_boxform").valid() === true)  { 
                var data = $("#BA_boxform").serialize();
                $.post('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php', data, function()    {


                }, 'json');
        } else
                { 
            return; 
                }
        },
        success:  function(msg) {
                $("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered a box");
                //$("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
        }

    });


});
```

Comment: Your expectation is correct. And you shouldn't need to call `.valid()`, since it shouldn't get there unless it's valid. Can you make a fiddle demonstrating it?

Comment: @Barmar here you go http://jsfiddle.net/HsqgZ/1/ ignore the php calls but you will see the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `success` function is called for each input that successfully validates, not only when the entire form is valid. From the documentation:

> If specified, the error label is displayed to show a valid element. If a String is given, its added as a class to the label. If a Function is given, its called with the label (as a jQuery object) and the validated input (as a DOM element). The label can be used to add a text like “ok!”.

The form won't be submitted until all fields validate successfully. If you want to display a message when the form is all good, do it in your `submitHandler` function.

Here's my version that works. ([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/HsqgZ/9/))

I removed the `.valid()` check in the submit handler; it's redundant because the submit handler isn't called unless the form is valid. I moved the message "You have entered a box" to before calling `$.post()` because the fiddle isn't able to post anything; this just proves that we got there.

```
$(function () {

    $.validator.setDefaults({

        errorClass: 'form_error',
        errorElement: 'div'
    });

    $("#BA_boxform").validate({
        rules: {
            BA_customer: {
                required: true
            },
            customerdept: {
                required: true
            },
            customeraddress: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_service: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_box: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_destdate: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_authorised: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            BA_customer: {
                required: '<br />* required: You must select a customer'
            },
            customerdept: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a department"
            },
            customeraddress: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a customer address"
            },
            BA_service: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a service level"
            },
            BA_box: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must enter a box number for intake"
            },
            BA_destdate: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must enter a destruction date"
            },
            BA_authorised: {
                required: "<br />* required"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function () {
            $("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered a box");
            var data = $("#BA_boxform").serialize();
            $.post('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php', data, function () {

                $("#BA_addbox").html($("#BA_addbox").html() + "<br>You have entered a box");
            }, 'json');
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            //$("#BA_addbox").html("You have entered a box");
            //$("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
        }

    });


});
```

Comment: I have moved to submtHandler but now the message does not display at all. I have updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/HsqgZ/4/ is it in the correct place. thanks

Comment: Your customer menu doesn't have anything in it, so the form never validates.

Comment: sorry i do not understand your comment. are you referring to #BA_boxform

Comment: I'm referring to `BA_customer`. There's nothing in the menu except the  label.

Comment: The select is populated from db call. I have updated the fiddle with jquery which does that. thanks http://jsfiddle.net/HsqgZ/5/

Comment: There's still nothing in that menu. PHP doesn't run in fiddle.

Comment: In my menu it runs fine. why do we need the menu? the error is there even just clicking add box.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're supposed to pass the form as argument in the line:

```
submitHandler: function() { ... }
```

Maybe change it to:

```
submitHandler:function(form) { ... }
```

and then use the argument instead of the id to organise your data

Comment: I think that would only make a difference if you were binding the validator to multiple forms.

Comment: `submitHandler` must be spelled with a capital `H`.  Notice the error on your second instance.